ASP WebForms DataTable.js columns undefined after PostBack
So we are building a simple e-commerce web application that has an admin functionality, In our products section  I've used a GridView to display the existing products then used DataTables.js for the filtering and pagination it is working perfectly but when i try and click an asp button it will postback then the functionality of the DataTables.js is gone and throws an error "col is undefined DataTable"
Before clicking edit
As you can see here the filters and pagination is all gone
After clicking edit
Here is the page load code
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       
         
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GetProductData();
       
            }
           

        }

Here is the instantiation of the datatable
   <script>

      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=ProductList.ClientID%>').DataTable({
                responsive: {
                    details: false
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


I tried recreating the table after clicking the "Edit" button to no avail.
